# Enterprise Architect - Fastest way to find all elements of a stereotype

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

We use a method in C# to determine all elements of a stereotypes but this is very slow:

```
    public List<EA.Element> findElementsByStereotype(string stereotype){
        List<EA.Element> result = new List<EA.Element>();
        String xmlQueryResult = repository.SQLQuery(
                                        "select obj1.object_id " +
                                        "from t_object obj1 " +
                                        "where obj1.stereotype = '" + stereotype + "';");
        XmlDocument xml = Tools.XMLUtil.convertStringToXMLDocument(xmlQueryResult);
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/EADATA/Dataset_0/Data/Row");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList){
            result.Add(repository.GetElementByID(Convert.ToInt32(xn.InnerText)));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Do you know a more performant solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go fast, XML is never your friend. Luckily, the EA API provides a different way of retrieving a set of elements: `Repository.GetElementSet()`, which returns an `EA.Collection` of `EA.Element`s from either a comma-separated list of element IDs, or from an SQL query.

```
public List<EA.Element> findElementsByStereotype(string stereotype) {
    List<EA.Element> result = new List<EA.Element>();
    foreach (EA.Element element in repository.GetElementSet("select Object_ID " +
             "from t_object where Stereotype='" + stereotype + "'", 2)) {
        result.Add(element);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please note that I haven't verified that this runs faster. I'm assuming it would, but it's possible that `GetElementSet()` does essentially the same XML parsing that you're doing under the hood. But if nothing else, it's shorter.

Comment: Note that the time consuming part is not the parsing of the XML. It is the getElementById() and getElementSet() calls. Both calls create on my computer aprox 20 Element-Objects per second (Java). Which is very, very slow.